# How to read certain parts of a txt file in python?

Tags: python, file

How to read certain part of a txt file in python?, i got this file:

```
Products:

123: banana.

321: apple.

555: orange.

clients:

1: james wood.

2: haley butterware.
```

what i need is take for example just the part of products and copy it to a list, but just the part of products. not the client's part. I know that you will tell me "Why don't you use database", well that's because i must use txt file.

Comment: read line by line, stop when you get to clients.

Comment: I edited your question--Did I get your file contents correct? Please show us the exact output you want from that input. Also, what work have you done on this problem so far? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would suggest using regular expressions to pattern match categories from the list of values

Answer (score 0):

you can run over it with a for loop if you know the exact syntax:

```
new_lst=[]
for line in file:
    if line[:7]=='clients'
        break
    elif line!='/* Products:'
        new_lst.append(line)
```

that's of course after using the open() method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking, so I have written a pretty simple and readable example which you can modify, to meet your needs if this doesn't meet them

Code:

```
arr = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "clients:" in line:
            break
        elif "Products:" not in line:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if len(line) > 0:
                arr.append(line)
        else:
            pass

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['123: banana.', '321: apple.', '555: orange.']
```